# testing order on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the following controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def index
    @users = User.all.order(email: :asc)
  end
end
```

How do I write a rspec test that checks the `index` def orders all users via email in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe "#index" do
  it "orders by email ascending" do
    user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "bb@aol.com")
    user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "aa@aol.com")

    get :index

    expect(assigns(:users).to_a).to eq([user2, user1])
  end
end
```

Comment: close but not there yet
     
       expected: [#<User id: 1260, name: "Fabian Connelly", email: "aa@spgroup.com.sg", created_at: "2018-05-02 01:31:...53", updated_at: "2018-05-02 01:31:53", provider: nil, uid: nil, token: nil, token_expires_at: nil>]
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1260, name: "Fabian Connelly", email: "aa@spgroup.com.sg", creat...3", updated_at: "2018-05-02 01:31:53", provider: nil, uid: nil, token: nil, token_expires_at: nil>]>

Comment: Ah! Works now. Thanks! 